# PHP write to mysql doesn't work though Firebug reports back Connected OK Everything seems OK

Tags: php, mysql

This is the Ajax call handler and checks are made on connection, prep, bind and execute and they all seem to be OK (checks nicked from elsewhere on this site), but no record gets added.  Firebug just comes back with the Connected OK and the Everything seems OK after all the checks.  I'm new to this stuff and totally at a loss.  Any help gratefully received.  Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
 error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
    && ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']==='XMLHttpRequest')) {

    require_once '../../htconfig/dbconf.php';

    $sql =  new mysqli($db['hostname'],$db['username'],$db['password'],$db['database']);
    if (!$sql -> connect_errno) {
        echo 'Connected OK';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Somethings wrong';
    exit;
    };

    if (isset($_POST['f4'])) {
        $f1 =   $_POST['f1'];
        $f2 =   $_POST['f2'];
        $f3 =   $_POST['f3'];
        $f4 =   $_POST['f4'];
        $f5 =   $_POST['f5'];
        $f6 =   $_POST['f6'];
        $f7 =    $_POST['f7'];
        $f8 =  $_POST['f8'];
        $f9 =    $_POST['f9'];

        $stmt = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO blatto (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        if ( false===$stmt ) {
          // and since all the following operations need a valid/ready statement object
          // it doesn't make sense to go on
          // you might want to use a more sophisticated mechanism than die()
          // but's it's only an example
          echo 'Prepare statemnt failure';
          die('\n prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));

        $rc = $stmt->bind_param('ssssddiis', $f1, $f2, $f3, $f4, $f5, $f6, $f7, $f8, $f9 );
        // bind_param() can fail because the number of parameter doesn't match the placeholders in the statement
        // or there's a type conflict(?), or ....
        if ( false===$rc ) {
          // again execute() is useless if you can't bind the parameters. Bail out somehow.
          echo 'Param bind failure';
          die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
        }

        $rc = $stmt->execute();
        // execute() can fail for various reasons. And may it be as stupid as someone tripping over the network cable
        // 2006 "server gone away" is always an option
        if ( false===$rc ) {
          echo 'Execute failure';
          die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
        }

        $stmt->close();
        }
        else {
            echo ' Everything seems OK';
        }
    };
}
?>
```

I've added the following (also nicked from this site) to the Ajax call and they return the success message with a status of 200 and status text 'OK'.  Still nothing written to the database.

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   alert('An error occurred... Look at the console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I, Console tab) for more information!');

    $('#result').html('<p>status code: '+jqXHR.status+'</p><p>errorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>'+jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
    console.log('jqXHR:');
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log('textStatus:');
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log('errorThrown:');
    console.log(errorThrown);

    },

/**
 * A function to be called if the request succeeds.
 */
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   $('#result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed. Look at the console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I, Console tab) for more information! ');
    console.log('jqXHR:');
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log('textStatus:');
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log('data:');
    console.log(data);

}
```

I created a new page that contains only a button and the Ajax call with fixed data.  It reports success too but no record is added.  I copied the SQL statement and pasted it into the PHPMyadmin SQL box with the same fixed values and ran it and all was well, a record was added.  Is suicide the only option?
I know the Ajax call makes it to the php script because it sends back the echo strings placed at different points.  The f4 check is a red herring because the Ajax call is only made if it is set and in the correct format and I have taken the client jscript, put it in a bare page and given it correct data for each of the fields and made the Ajax call.  It behaves in exactly the same way and returns the same check strings and still doesn't write to the database.  The $sql object is created, so the db connection is good.  Prepare, bind and execute generate no errors.  I also added another echo, not shown above, which shows that the php script runs all the way to the end without encountering an error.  Like I said, I'm new to this stuff so forgive my ignorance when I ask if 5xx and 4xx errors can occur and not be caught by any of the checks in the php script?  The only 4xx error I could see occurring would be if the path to the include dbconf.php is wrong.  I'll make sure that path is wrong and retest to see if the error gets picked up.  I've no idea how to generate a server side 5xx error.
Thanks all for the suggestions.

OK, I changed the filename in the include_once line to a fake one and it generated a file not found fatal error and exited at that point.  So 4xx errors are handled, or at least the 404.

Comment: You should play nice with [HTTP](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html) and return a 500 error code in case of error

Comment: Also are you sure $_POST[f4] isset? All your code depends on it...

Comment: Your code says returns `"Everything seems OK"` when `$_POST["f4"]` is not set.

Comment: The Ajax call isn't made unless f4 is set so the php test here is somewhat redundant, and as far as I can see the if isset clause terminates immediately after the 'Everythings OK' echo, not before it.  I'll give the 500 error a whirl and see if it comes up with anything.  Thanks all.

Comment: I've added the following (also nicked from this site) to the Ajax call and they return the success message with a status of 200 and and status text 'OK'.  Still nothing written to the database.

Comment: I'd try to run the statement directly in the database console and see what the result is. Continue to simplify until there is nowhere for the bug to hide.

Comment: To the point made by @mTorres - unless you have PHP do something to send back a non-200 HTTP response code, the AJAX client will always trigger your success handler regardless of whether the server-side script fails or not, as even a fatal error PHP script will return a 200 HTTP response. This is of course assuming the request makes it to the script and some other web server error is not encountered (i.e. 4XX, 5XX, etc.)